# Is OAuth 2.0 suitable for first-party mobile app clients? Can I use user credentials to obtain a token without redirecting or prompting the user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

I have a first-party authorization server and I'm developing a first-party native mobile app and a SPA as a client. I noticed that the latest version of OAuth 2.0 no longer supports the "password grand type" and recommends using the "authorization_code grand type" instead, for mobile apps and SPAs.

My app has a native login screen and my SPA has its own unique login screen, and I want to avoid redirecting the user to the authorization server's login page or prompting a popup for login credentials since the authorization server is a trusted first-party server.

I'm wondering if OAuth 2.0 is still a good choice for first-party mobile app clients or SPA in this situation, and if there is a way to directly request a token through an HTTP request flow using user credentials obtained from the native mobile app login screen?

Any advice or insights on how to proceed would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I found these two articles on this topic.

https://www.ory.sh/oauth2-openid-connect-do-you-need-use-cases-examples/
https://www.ory.sh/docs/hydra/concepts/before-oauth2

Comment: Worth noting that [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) grant type was removed from OAuth 2.1 spec.